# url change badly after send header in php

Tags: php

I am using header() function in php for changing url and redirect user to another page.
when the user is on the page "localhost/admin/index.php" ,  enter login information and try to login, header() function is used to redirect user to page 
"localhost/admin/homepage.php" but page address changes to "localhost/admin/localhost/admin/homepage.php"

header("Location: localhost/admin/homepage.php");

what is your solution for this problem?
Thank you

Comment: `header("Location: localhost/admin/homepage.php");` change this to `header("Location: homepage.php");`

Comment: or `header("Location: http://localhost/admin/homepage.php"); exit;` - RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
header("Location: ./homepage.php");
```

Or

```
header("Location: http://localhost/admin/homepage.php");
```

Comment: Please leave a comment if you down vote any answer, so we know what is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The path must be either an absolute URL or a URL relative to the current url.

```
header("Location: http://localhost/admin/homepage.php");
```

or

```
header("Location: homepage.php");
```

or

```
header("Location: /admin/homepage.php");
```

should all work. Make sure you `die` or `exit` or otherwise cease execution after the location header, as it won't prevent subsequent code from running on its own.